# Render handlebar helpers in jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to append a snippet into my main template(handlebars) using jquery

```
var appendToDiv = function(data){
   return `
       <div class='some class'>
          {{{formatDate ${data.created_at} 'MMM DD YYYY'}}}
        </div>
    `
}
```

where formatDate is a handlebar helper.

```
$('#content').append(appendToDiv(data))
```

the issue here is, the handlebar helper is not being compiled. hope the question is clear enough. any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean that the function returns mustache as a text? You definitely need to call the template engine before appending an html text.

Comment: Are you using handlebars in front end or backend

Comment: handlebars in the frontend

Comment: @Artem, the function is supposed to return a string I can append to a div in the template. `<div class='someclass'>May 02 2018
</div>`

Comment: @lacasera yes, I understand. But does it call the handlebars templater?

Comment: @Artem no, how can I do this in jQuery?

Comment: @lacasera after receiving a string and before inserting it into the DOM you need to call the templater like `Handlebars.compile(string)(context);`. Just as it was a regular HTML render method on a server.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally went about it.

in the main template file, `index.handlebars`, I created a partial like so

```
<div id='content'></div>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="someclass">
       {{formatDate mydate 'MM DD YYYY'}}
    </div>
</script>
```

in the js file,

```
var template = document.getElementById('template')
var view = Handlebars.compile(template)
var templateToDisplay = view(mydate)
$('#content').append(templateToDisplay)
```

Hope someone else finds this useful .